# Angular 4 http batch requests

Tags: angular, http, angular2-template, angular2-services

To optimize my API calls, I would like to make batch requests using this module
https://github.com/jonsamwell/ngx-http-batcher#examples.
As per the example, the configuration is set in AppModule.

```
export function httpBatchConfigurationFactory() {
  return new HttpBatchConfigurationCollection([
    new HttpBatchConfiguration({
      rootEndpointUrl: "https://api.myservice.com",
      batchEndpointUrl: "https://api.myservice.com/$batch"
    })]);
};
```

And in the providers, I have set

```
{ provide: HttpBatchConfigurationCollection, useFactory: httpBatchConfigurationFactory },
    { provide: Http, useClass: HttpBatcher }
```

Everything works fine, when this configuration is static.
My application identifies the **rootEnPointUrl**, only after the user has logged into the application.

How can I add a new HttpBatchConfiguration to this **HttpBatchConfigurationCollection**, after user authentication?

Comment: Why not use an injectable service instead of provide a factory during module setup? So that you can change configuration whenever you like even after app initialised.

Comment: @Xinan Indeed a simple injection of the http batch collection worked.

Comment: @Xinan , add your comment as answer or i will add it here :)

Comment: @nkuma_12 thanks for reminding ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an injectable service instead of providing a factory during module setup? So that you can change configuration whenever you like even after app initialised.